How to attach panel at header section of view3d?
I am able to add the panel at side bar of UI regin, but not able to add same panel at header section.
I want to create button at header section, on click button panel should be visible and it should look like that panel is attached to button.
In reference image you can see that the panel at sidebar and button, where to be created at header section which has been marked in red area.


These menus you describe are called popover menus. Their API is detailed here:
popover - UILayout(bpy_struct) - Blender Python API
Assuming the following code, which is the ui_panel_simple.py template provided in Blender, modified to respect the current class naming convention and to be inserted in the Viewport's sidebar instead of the objects properties in order to match to your situation:
import bpy

class VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Viewport Sidebar > Item tab"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Define the popover GUI
Defining the popover GUI is just a matter of a single function that will use layout.popover() to define our popover's name, icon and content (aka the bpy.types.panel class name).
def define_hello_world_popover(self, context):
    """Defines the Hello World popover button's appearance in the header."""
    layout = self.layout
    layout.popover(
        panel="VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover", # class name of our panel
        text="Hello",
        icon='WORLD_DATA'
    )

You can use the Icon Viewer addon to browse and get addons names from the text editor's sidebar:

Insert the popover in the existing Header GUI
To insert that into the header, all we need is to append or prepend that function to the header's GUI defining class during the register() function. But let's not forget to also remove it during the unregister() function to avoid issues when disabling the addon.
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.prepend(define_hello_world_popover)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.remov(define_hello_world_popover)

Make sure it works in that new context
Your script does different things than mine, but it's always good practice to be mindful when you change context to double-check it will not cause issues.
In the template I used as base, it shows the active object's name. It will always work because it's a GUI that is shown in the Object properties, which only shows if there's an active object. So there by design there is a pre-existing condition that makes sure my GUI will only be run in a scenario that will work.
But moving that GUI to the viewport's popover means that the GUI can be shown while there's no active object, which will lead to errors.
So I have to modify my panel GUI to handle that case:
if obj:
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text=f"Active object is: {obj.name}")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj, "name")
else:
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="No active object")

Result
So the whole script looks like this:
import bpy

class VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Popover in the Viewport Header"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'HEADER'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        if obj:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text=f"Active object is: {obj.name}")
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(obj, "name")
        else:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="No active object")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def define_hello_world_popover(self, context):
    """Defines the Hello World popover button's appearance in the header."""
    layout = self.layout
    layout.popover(
        panel="VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover",
        text="Hello",
        icon='WORLD_DATA'
    )

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.append(define_hello_world_popover)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_hello_world_popover)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.remove(define_hello_world_popover)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Or if you prefer to see a differential:
Blender viewport sidebar Panel to header Popover - Diffchecker

Refining the placement
Appending "adds" the popover after the designated element, while prepending adds it before.
There are multiple elements you can append/prepend to in the viewport's header. VIEW3D_HT_header is the whole header, so it lets you insert your popover at the far right or far left of it. There is another class you can append/prepend to: VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus, which lets you insert around the main editor menus (View, Select, Add, etc).
So for example, if you wanted to add your popover before those menus, your popover definition function would be registered like this:
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.prepend(define_hello_world_popover)


Note that other addons may also be added there, and they are ordered by the order in which they are loaded.
As for placing in other places such as what you highlighted in your screenshot, I believe it may be possible, using custom layouts and controlling the draw order of UI components, but it is more complex than appending or prepending. It requires a deeper understanding of Blender’s drawing API and AFAIK involves things like overriding existing layouts, which adds some challenges, like layout breakage when Blender’s internal design changes, potential usability issues if the interface becomes cluttered or non-intuitive, and performance concerns from excessive redraw calls or overloaded regions.
So I reckon it's best to stick to the easily available system, and also follow the official GUI guidelines:
Human interface guidelines - Blender Developer Documentation

Thanks a lot. Its working
